# debugging python script in analyzing log files

Tags: python

I have a python script to process a bunch of log files. It opens up each log and parse each line, and stores the information in data structures. After scanning through the file, it collects the statistics and generate an output file.

I'm testing it against various logs, and it went ok for 20+ different files. But recently, I found it consistently fails on a particular file with 4381k lines. It somehow cannot complete the scanning and parsing.

I'm in the process of narrow down the problem right now, I don't know exactly what was happening there. I'd really need some input in order to find the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your code so we can analize it ?

Comment: We need a traceback (full error message) to help you

Comment: It doesn't show an error message. All I'm seeing right now is that it is not able to complete the processing, over 12 hours. This doesn't make sense, so I'm printing messages to assist my debugging. So far, I haven't identified a good direction yet.

Comment: Are you the author of the script?  Can you post it?

Comment: Since your program doesn't stop, I assume there is an endless loop. In order to find the function containing it, you can [profile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/profile.html) your code. Just run the script with the profiler and after an hour or so, abort it with ctrl+c. Then see which function was executed most/longest and you have a direction ;)

Comment: After debugging it over night and print out line number of which it was processing, it appears the program is still processing, only it was very slow. It now processed 2520k lines, which is about 60% of the file. I'm wondering if python is in generally this slow, or it has something to do with big data structure it was holding?